# Cannot lookup EJB3 from ServletContextListener in JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, ejb, jndi

I have created an EJB timer with a local interface and I am not able to do JNDI lookup for it from a ServletContextListener.

Here is part of the EJB code:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = "TimedFileDeletion")
public class TimedFileDeletionBean implements TimedFileDeletionBeanLocal {

 @Resource
    TimerService timerService;
 private String timerInfo = "FileDeletionTimer";

    public void startTimer() {
    ....
    }

    public boolean isItRunning() {
    ....
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Here is the local interface:

```
public interface TimedFileDeletionBeanLocal {

 public void startTimer();

 public boolean isItRunning();
}
```

And here is the ServletContextListener:

```
public class StartupEventHandler implements ServletContextListener {

 TimedFileDeletionBeanLocal timedFileDeletionBeanLocal;

    public StartupEventHandler() {
     try {
   InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
   timedFileDeletionBeanLocal = (TimedFileDeletionBeanLocal) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/TimedFileDeletion");

  } catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        if(!timedFileDeletionBeanLocal.isItRunning()) {
         timedFileDeletionBeanLocal.startTimer();
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

For the lookup I also used the following Strings but none of the worked:
- java:comp/env/TimedFileDeletion
- java:comp/TimedFileDeletion
- java:TimedFileDeletion
- TimedFileDeletion

In all cases I was getting a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While starting JBoss it logs all the local/remote interfaces & their jndi configuration.

**JBoss startup log :**

```
15:26:47,394 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local-com.cc.hrms.bl.accounts.generalaccount.session.AccountSummarySessionBeanLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

**Lookup :**

```
initialCtx.lookup("hrms/AccountSummarySessionBean/local-com.cc.hrms.bl.accounts.generalaccount.session.AccountSummarySessionBeanLocal");
```

I am using JBoss-5 & have generalized method for lookup, just giving interface name.

You can modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked up the name in the logs, used that name it works.